# Nest JS server returning 404 response to all the routes after changing node JS version on my machine

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I am running my Nest JS application on my local server's PORT 3000 and my node version is 16.5.0. My application has multiple routes and all were giving correct responses. There was a requirement where I had to downgrade the node version to 14.17.0. After this change, I started my server again and here the problem comes. All the routes started giving the response like `POST /user 404 not found` and `GET /user/:id 404 not found`.

I have reverted back to node version 16.5.0 and removed the `node_modules` and re-installed it again and restarted the server as well. But still, I am getting the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

All the approaches I tried above failed to resolve the issue. The only way which resolved the issue is by restarting the system and running the server again.

Comment: So, you restart the server, and everything works, then you downgrade to node 14 and get 404, then you reboot and even with node 14 you will not see any 404 errors anymore?

Comment: Yes., after re-starting, I am not seeing any errors with node 14 as well

Comment: Can you try a `npm run build` after switching the node version?

Comment: @AliMolaei., What exactly npm run build would do? Will it create a new dist folder? I have tried that by deleting the dist folder as well but it didn't solve the issue.